# $\{ x\in X: f \text{ is continuous at } x\}$ is borel

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, borel-sets

Let $X, Y$ be two metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Prove that $A:= \{ x\in X: f$ is continuous at x$\}$ is a borel subset of X. I'm stuck here for good. I'm trying to use an equivalent definition of continuity that uses inverse images but I cant adapt the definition I know to point continuity. Any ideas or hints? I also tried writing A as $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{m, n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n,m}}$, where $A_{n,m} = \{ x \in X: f(D(x, \frac{1}{m}))\subset D(f(x), \frac{1}{n})\}$, no luck though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big hint: define $O_n=\{ x \in X : \exists \delta > 0 \: \forall y,z \in B_\delta(x) \: d_Y(f(y),f(z))<1/n \}$. Show that $O_n$ is open and that $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$.

Comment: Alright, I get it. Thanks, but I cant see how would one think of these open sets. I suppose one would have to think the sequential definition of continuity and the fact that all convergent sequences are Cauchy. Could you explain your way of thought please?

Comment: @Kps This is just the way I did it in an assignment several years ago. Now I think that the more intuitive way to do it is to look at $U_n=\{ x \in X : \exists \delta>0 \: \forall y \in B_\delta(x) \: d_Y(f(x),f(y))<1/n \}$. It's not hard to see that $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$, because $U_n$ consists of those points where $f$ satisfies "the definition of continuity but only down to $\epsilon=1/n$". So the intersection forces $\epsilon$ to shrink down as it must.

Comment: @Kps I think this way of doing it might also work, in particular I think you can still show that $U_n$ is open by exploiting the triangle inequality (so as to relate $d_Y(f(y),f(z))$ to $d_Y(f(x),f(y))$ and $d_Y(f(x),f(z))$). This $O_n$ approach somehow lets you avoid this step because it *directly* gives information about $d_Y(f(y),f(z))$ without having to refer back to $f(x)$. Anyway, this is *fundamentally* a property about metric space-valued functions, so there will need to be *some* direct reference to the metric. There is no way to make a purely topological version of this proof.

Comment: So you're implying that this proposition does not hold for topological spaces that cant be equipped with a metric. Well, thanks a lot, your explanation was very helpful and thorough!

Comment: Now that I see this again, I dont think these $U_n$ in the comments are open